# Initialize categorical data to predefined centroids for kmodes

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, categorical-data, centroid

I want to cluster real-world categorical data on five predefined centroids using kmodes. My code looks like this:

```
real_df = [['B' 'A' 'A' ... 'D']
 ['D' 'I' 'D' ... ]
 ['D' 'I' 'D' ... ]
 ...
 ['K' 'F' 'D' ... 'D']
 ['D' 'P' 'D' ... 'D']]

cen = [['P', 'S', 'M', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'S'],
 ['P', 'P', 'P', 'S', 'I', 'M', 'W',],
 ['M', 'W', 'F', 'R', 'S', 'A', 'I'],
 ['P', 'S', 'M', 'F', 'R', 'S', 'A'],
 ['P', 'S', 'M', 'M', 'P', 'P', 'P',]]
km = KModes(n_clusters=5, init=cen, n_init = 1, verbose = 0)
fitClusters = km.fit_predict(real_df)
```

However, I get the following error message:

[image: Error]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found the solution connecting with Nico de Vos on github
https://github.com/nicodv/kmodes

When you provide initial clusters with `init = ...`, you have to provide an encoded clusters centroid array.

The code is basically the rank order (A to Z, low to high) of all unique values for each attribute, starting with 0.

In your example, if you use all 26 letters in your first attribute, then A=0, B=1, C=2, etc. If one letter is missing then Z is 24 and not 25
So the first line of your array would be `[15, 18, 12, 15, 15, 15, 18]`

Useful code:
When you have the model, get the encoded clusters centroids with `model._enc_cluster_centroids`

Get the mapping with `model._enc_map`